# Angularjs how can I unit test a Service which depends on another Service with promises?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, deferred

How can I test a service which depends on another service. I currently get Service1Provider not found error in this implementation. How can I properly inject Service1 so I can unit test Service2? Thanks for any tips or tricks.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcabnettek/JJ9Rk/)
[gist](https://gist.github.com/hcabnettek/5780431)

```
!function(ng){
'use strict';

 var module = ng.module('foo.services', []);

(function($ng, $module) {
  function Service($q) {

    return {
        bar: function(a,b,c){

            var baz = a+b+c;
            return function(d,e,f){

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if(baz > 0){
                  deferred.resolve({result: baz + d + e + f });
                } else {
                  deferred.reject({ err: 'baz was <= 0'})
                }
                return deferred.promise;

            }
        }
    };
  }

   $module.factory("Service1", ['$q', Service]);

 })(ng, module);

  (function($ng, $module) {
    function Service(Service1) {

       function doSomething(){

        var result;
        var whatever = Service1.bar(5,6,7);

         var promise = whatever(8,9,10);
        promise.then(function(data){

            result = data.result;
            //data.result should be 45 here
        }, function(err){

        });

        return result;
    }

    return {
        bam:doSomething
    };
}

  $module.factory("Service2", ["Service1", Service]);

  })(ng, module);
}(angular);


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['foo.services']);
```

Comment: Hcabnettek, I can only suggest that Service2 would need to be modified to accept a service as a parameter passed to `doSomething`, otherwise Service2's dependency on Service1 is impenetrably internal to Service2. If you are looking for an answer to what might be wrong, then `result` can't be returned directly from from `doSomething` - you need to return `promise`.

Comment: In fact, the modification needs to be slightly more extensive. The returned promise needs to take account of the chained `.then()`, whose callback should return data.result` (I think).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just testing Service2 then you should try to eliminate any dependency on Service1 in the test. Your test could have something like:

```
module('foo.services', function($provide) {
  $provide.value('Service1', MockService1());
});
```

This will give the return value from the function MockService1 instead of actually using the service, whenever it is injected.

Then you have MockService1 function return a skeleton of the actual service with the same function. In your test you can then wait for the promise to be resolved by doing something like this:

```
bar: function(...) {
  var def = $q.defer();
  $timeout(function() {
    def.resolve('test');
  });
  return def.promise;
}

// This is in your test
bar.then( /* .... some tests */ );
// This executes the timeout and therefor the resolve
$rootScope.$digest();
$timeout.flush();
```

Hope this helped

Comment: This is not a bad idea, however, if the service being mocked up is huge or unknown (with a lot of unexpected errors, for example,) it's hardly going to be helpful. In my case, I'm testing with [express-cassandra](https://github.com/masumsoft/express-cassandra) and doing a valid mock up would take months of work...